# Agglomerate adjecent cells and their neighbours of the same type to clusters with python

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to agglomerate adjacent cells (and their neighbours) that have the same type (integer from 1 to 10) into new clusters by assigning them to a cluster id.

As visualised here for some of the clusters:

[image]

Currently, I use an abbreviation from Breadth-First search to go through all neighbours and their neighbours and then assign a cluster-id to all found neighbours of the same type. Since my data set is fairly big (<3 Million grid cells) this operation would take days in its current form.

My function that I run in a loop choosing cells by chance until all cells have been assigned a cluster id:

```
def bfs(df, grid_id):
    visited = []
    queue = []
    visited.append(grid_id)
    queue.append(grid_id)
    base_pred = df.loc[grid_id, "class"]
    while queue:
        _ = queue.pop(0)
        n, e = get_n_e_index(grid_id)
        neighbours = get_same_neighbours(base_pred, n, e, agglo_df)
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited.append(neighbour)
                queue.append(neighbour)
                queue = queue + get_same_neighbours(base_pred, n, e, agglo_df)

    return visited
```

`visited` is used to assign the same cluster_id

`get_same_neighbours` just returns neighbours of a given cell that have the same type

Before I ended up validating the approach I came to the conclusion that it's ultimately to slow and was wondering if anybody knows of an algorithm fast enough to solve this. Searching online for a solution didn't help.

**Edit**: That it took so long wasn't an issue of the algorithm, but me forgetting to reduce the possible start cells to only those who haven't been touched before.

**Edit2**:

`get_n_e_index` just converts a string ID to North East Integers

```
def get_same_neighbours(base_class, north, east, df):
    neighbours = []
    grid_ids = df["ids"].values
    for i in [-1, 1, 0]:
        for j in [-1, 1, 0]:
            n = int(north + i)
            e = int(east + j)
            grid_id = get_grid_id(n, e)
            invalid = [(-1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, -1), (-1, -1)] # invalid combinations
            if grid_id in grid_ids and (j, i) not in invalid and base_class == df.loc[grid_id, "class"]:
                neighbours.append(grid_id)
    return neighbours
```

`get_grid_id` converts north (n) and east (e) integers to the string id of the grid cell.

Comment: 3 million grid cells doesn't seem like such a large number. Images have several million pixels and this kind of operation is done in seconds by even basic image editing software. An exhaustive search by iterating over the grid dimensions and checking of cell neighbours should be fast enough even if the grid is sparsely populated.

Comment: In any case, you've a hidden linear search inside your inner loop: `if neighbour not in visited`. You'll want to use a set instead of a list.

Comment: The last line of your inner loop doesn't make sense to me, you're adding the neighbours of the current cell into the queue one by one, and also adding the whole set of neighbours for each neighbour.

Comment: sorry I've had a mistake in my while loop that made it go over each cell even tho some might already have been assigned a cluster. Now it would take 4 hours for all. Still there seems to be something wrong.

Last line adds neighbours of the currently looked add neighbour to the queue. If not I dont understand what I actually did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a couple of mistakes. Note that for ~3 million cells, this should work within about a second.

As pointed out in the comments, `visited` should be a set for `O(1)` lookup.

Second, `queue = queue + get_same_neighbours(base_pred, n, e, agglo_df)` can get very slow if the queue gets very long, as it creates a copy of the queue. Instead, simply `append` the new items.

Finally, your `queue` is not actually a queue, but a list. Therefore, popping the first element takes `O(n)` time. Instead you can use a queue (`deque` in python), or you can pop the last element instead, which will turn Breadth-firsth search into Depth-first search, which should work just as well.

Apart from this, I think the only remaining problems are in the graph/grid representation. Storing it as a dataframe seems to often require parsing the entire dataframe to find cells. If you store it as a multidimensional array (be it `list`s or numpy `array`s) or even as a `dict`, you can find any cell in `O(1)` time. Therefore I'd suggest first preprocessing the data from the dataframe into another data structure that grants easy access.

Comment: I've added explanations / the code of both get functions in the edit as I feel like I could learn a lot here. Implementing deque and set() decreased the time to around 4 hours for all cells...

Comment: @Phil I've edited a paragraph in based on your edit. I think the remaining problems are due to the DF representation.